# Auth0 callback redirect for Development Environment

Tags: auth0

Auth0 have a wonderfull piece of documentation and sometimes even if you read through it 1000 times it just fails to make sense to me personally so hopefully maybe someone else had a similar problem.

What do I want?

Ii I log in from my local host environment which is compiled with the auth0.WebAuth object looking like this:

```
 auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
     clientID: 'adscsdcascascascasdcsdac',
     domain: 'webatom.auth0.com',
     responseType: 'token id_token',
     audience: 'https://api.webatom.com',
     redirectUri: 'http://localhost:5000/callback',        
     scope: 'openid profile'
 });
```

I want it to redirect the developer to the localhost.

If I log in (or the user logs in) from the production environemnt ie. from jtrade.pro I want them to be redirected to jtrade.pro/callback. Obviously the object in the production version looks like this (with a different redirect uri):

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: 'adscsdcascascascasdcsdac',
    domain: 'webatom.auth0.com',
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: 'https://api.webatom.com',
    redirectUri: 'http://jtrade.pro/callback',        
    scope: 'openid profile'
});
```

As far as I understood, thats how you do it. Pass the uri and you will be redirected to the required page if the uri is whitelisted and comma separated in the client settings. Beautifull, I whitelisted and comma separated.

Last step, the hosted page.

```
var lock = new Auth0Lock(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
  auth: {
    redirectUrl:  config.callbackURL,
    responseType: 'token',
    params: config.internalOptions
  },
  assetsUrl:  config.assetsUrl,
  allowedConnections: connection ? [connection] : null,
  rememberLastLogin: !prompt,
  language: language,
  languageDictionary: languageDictionary,
  theme: {

  },
  prefill: loginHint ? { email: loginHint, username: loginHint } : null,
  closable: false,
});
```

Redirect URL is set to config.callbackURL which is as far as I understood makes auth0 look into the whitelist and see if one of the provided uri is there and redirect the user if it is.

However, this doesn't happen. Auth0 only redirects the user to the first uri in the whitelist. I can't find a suitable solution for this issue. Hopefully someone ran into this situation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the above, and the behaviour I see is different - Auth0 correctly uses the redirectUri passed in. You should double-check all your settings a something is wrong with your setup / configuration. Below, is a recap of findings:

[image]

Client App (used React sample out of the box):

```
 auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
    redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
    audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    scope: 'openid'
  });
```

Translates to each of the following:

```
https://demo.auth0.com/login?client=zalZ1MxxxxxxxxxxxZ5xfZga&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&response_type=token id_token&scope=openid&audience=https://demo.auth0.com/userinfo&nonce=2OfVCpn-4Ka9k33h50Y5YjNgw8nsxE5B

https://demo.auth0.com/login?client=zalZ1MxxxxxxxxxxxZ5xfZga&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001/callback&response_type=token id_token&scope=openid&audience=https://demo.auth0.com/userinfo&nonce=kDNsP5Sfp1M0ydJ57h7eG.S_sNkO7gRs
```

Using the default Auth0 HLP, you will have the following:

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.18/lock.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Decode utf8 characters properly
    var config = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob('@@config@@'))));
    config.extraParams = config.extraParams || {};
    var connection = config.connection;
    var prompt = config.prompt;
    var languageDictionary;
    var language;

    if (config.dict && config.dict.signin && config.dict.signin.title) {
      languageDictionary = { title: config.dict.signin.title };
    } else if (typeof config.dict === 'string') {
      language = config.dict;
    }
    var loginHint = config.extraParams.login_hint;

    var lock = new Auth0Lock(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
      auth: {
        redirectUrl: config.callbackURL,
        responseType: (config.internalOptions || {}).response_type ||
          config.callbackOnLocationHash ? 'token' : 'code',
        params: config.internalOptions
      },
      assetsUrl:  config.assetsUrl,
      allowedConnections: connection ? [connection] : null,
      rememberLastLogin: !prompt,
      language: language,
      languageDictionary: languageDictionary,
      theme: {
        //logo:            'YOUR LOGO HERE',
        //primaryColor:    'green'
      },
      prefill: loginHint ? { email: loginHint, username: loginHint } : null,
      closable: false,
      // uncomment if you want small buttons for social providers
      // socialButtonStyle: 'small'
    });

    lock.show();
  </script>
```

This correctly calls back to the Client on the Port assigned in the original callback url (redirectUri).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that instead of calling the method auth0.authorize() which redirects the user to the /authorize endpoint I hardcoded the url and was redirecting the user to the /login endpoint and did not include any data in the params (ie inside the url string). You don't have to use the method you can also construct the string by yourself if you want. Complete guide on the method can be found [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v8#webauth-authorize-).